# What is the usefulness of Internal Stability?

Tags: control, stability

In the analysis of a feedback control system is it important that a sub-network be itself stable.  i.e. if I were to break apart the main complex system and just study a single feedback loop, is it significant that that sub-network be stable itself or does one just consider the whole larger network?.

[image]

Comment: What system? Do you mean "system" in general like a "plant" in control theory?

Comment: Yes.. exactly a plant in control system

Comment: To me, it is not clear what you really mean. I see only one single feedbacl loop. Which "system" could be "internally" unstable? The (passive) controlled system? To distinguish between "internal" and "overall" stability you need at least two feedback loops (one local and the other one overall).

Comment: Ohh.. i might i've misunderstood something?
So it has nothing to do with the internal stabilities of the internal components, but of the internal close loops?...
Well in that case please look at my edit..

Comment: Now - after presenting a new block diagram it is up to you to define your own term "internal stability". That means: Which loops are open and which do you want to close?

Comment: Actually all the loops ??...
I  am bit confused on the concepts.. I thought that it meant that the system system components were unstable...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The stability of a compound system is also influenced by the cancellation of poles and zeros RHP (right-half plane). In this case, the resulting system is stable when observed externally, but can exist internal signals which can grow without limit (in practice **saturation**, **damage**, ...). For example in the figure below, when applying a unit step in the input, the output of \$S_1\$ increases exponentially with the time, although the output of the series system is bounded.

[image: Dirceu composite]

Answer (score 1):

You need to study the whole and not the parts. Just looking at a S-domain analysis you can see where certain poles and zeros come from and it should be clear that if you remove certain poles and zeros by removing an larger scale feedback loop that the circuit will ring.  i.e. it's by tailoring the placement of these poles and zeros that allows the whole system to be stable or accomplish the designed control effect.

Comment: I do understand the basic understanding of how a system is stable, and how it is unstable.. 
but what I don't see is how the internal is calculated. 
I mean i would normaly just reduce the block diagram and thereby determine if the system is stable or not. 
But what i don't see how it will be usefull to know the internal stability , and how  I should  do it?

Comment: He is saying that the internal is not important. The entire system stability is all that really matters.

Comment: Hmm..  what could then be meant by internal stability...

Comment: It may or may NOT help, it very much depends upon what the equations that determine it's response look like.  You may require a sub-net to be stable or the outside loops may control an inherently unstable sub-net.

Comment: @user38544: I think "internal stability" is another term for "stability of the (outer, large) loop", if it is opened. As I have mentioned in my answer, this loop gain stability (loop gain has no RHP poles) is required for applying the simplified stability criterion.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it is not easy to answer the question because I am not quite sure about the background of your question.
Therefore, some general remarks to such a multi-loop system.

1.) Your block diagram shows three different loops - hence, we can define three different loop gain functions. Thus, we will have three differeent stability margins. In this context it is interesting to note that for converting this multi-loop sysytem into a single loop system you also have THREE different ways.
Thus, creating a single-loop system does not really simplify the problem.

2.) Next question: Which of the three margins defines overall stability? With other words: Which margin dominates over the other two? This cannot be answered in general. However, one can say that the SLOWEST loop (largest time constant) will dominate the main behaviour. In most cases and for a good design this is the outer (overall) loop.

3.) In some rare cases an internal loop is unstable (because it cannot be avoided) and must be stabilized using additional outer loops. In this case, we are not allowed to apply Nyquist´s simplified stability criterion (or BODE stability check) and we have to use Nyquist´s general criterion.